# Rename observations in Dataframe

Tags: r, rename

i have a dataframe in R and one column is called state. In this column all us states are abbreviated e.g. NY, ME etc. Now i need to rename these values with their full name e.g. new york, maine etc. I have tried multiple functions such as rename() or revalue(), but somehow they either give me an error notification or create a new value, which is not what i intend. Attached you can find one of my multiple failures. I am very thankful for all kinds of help, since i am stuck with this since a few days. Also Happy first Advent everyone!

```
str(rename(zipcode_new,
            "AL"="alaska","AK"="alaska","AR"="arizona","AZ"="arizona","CA"="california","CO"="colorado","CT"="conneticut","DE"="delaware","FL"="florida","GA"="georgia","HI"="hawaii","IA"="iowa","ID"="idaho","IL"="illinois","IN"="indiana","KS"="kansas","KY"="kentucky","LA"="louisiana","MA"="massachussets","MD"="maryland","ME"="maine","MN"="minnesota","MI"="michigan","MS"="mississippi","MS"="mississippi","MO"="missouri","MT"="montana","NE"="north carolina","ND"="north dakota","NH"="new hampshire","NJ"="new jersey","NM"="new mexico","NV"="nevada","NY"="new york","OH"="ohio","OK"="oklahoma","OR"="oregon","PA"="pennsylvania","SC"="south carolina","SD"="south dakota","TN"="tennessee","TX"="texas","UT"="utah","VA"="virginia","WA"="washington","WI"="wisconsin","WY"="wyoming"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier if we can make use of the inbuilt `state.name` and `state.abb`

```
df1$state <- with(df1, tolower(setNames(state.name, state.abb)[state]))
```

---

Using the OP's dataset

```
zipcode_new$state <- with(zipcode_new, tolower(setNames(state.name, 
             state.abb)[state]))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(state = sample(state.abb, 100, replace = TRUE),
         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your quick answer! Does this solution also work in my case because i already have a dataframe with quite a lot columns and i need to change it in there?

Comment: @Amy  I guess you are only interested in changing the `state` column, right?  If that is the cause it should work as I m only extracting the column and assigning it back.  Here, the trick is to match the values in the 'state' with a named vector and get the corresponding values of that vector

Comment: @Amy Not sure what is the case.  Do you have the `state` column as `factor`?  Check the `class(df1$state)` of your data?  In that case, you need `with(df1, tolower(setNames(state.name, state.abb)[as.character(state)]))`

Comment: You are right, i want to turn the state abbreviation into the statename. i have tried it and somehow it turns my whole df into only this variable. Maybe i am on the wrong track

Comment: @Amy If you check my code, I am only extracting the column named 'state' and assigning it back.  So, not sure how the whole data is changed

Comment: @Amy It would be better if you can `dput` a  small example i.e. `dput(droplevels(head(yourdata, 20)))` and post it in your question by editing

Comment: zipcode_new$state <- with(zipcode, tolower(setNames(state.name, state.abb)[as.character(state)]))
set.seed(24)
zipcode_new <- data.frame(state = sample(state.abb, 100, replace = TRUE),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE) This is the code i entered,  when doing so it reduces my zipcode_new variable to 1 variable with 100 obs. instead of 34 variable w/ 13197 variables. Could you please check if i did a mistake? i am deeply sorry!

Comment: @Amy You need only `zipcode_new$state <- with(zipcode, tolower(setNames(state.name, state.abb)[as.character(state)]))`  the second part from `set.seed(24)` I used for creating a reproducible example as there was no example in your post earlier :=)

Comment: @Amy My solution is working fine with the dput data you showed